# range.surroundContents in chrome extension is disabling right click

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, range, right-click

I'm building a chrome extension where selected text can have different highlighting styles applied to it. I used ranges to get this all to work, and I clone the range, put a span around it, and then delete the range and replace it with the cloned one. Everything seems fine except I've somehow managed to disable right clicking by triggering this behavior through the extension. I've narrowed it down the single line of `range.surroundContents(span)`, but here's the full code section:

```
// Determines the selected text
document.onmouseup = function() {
    var selection = document.getSelection();
    selection = getSelectedText(color);
};

// Finds the text selected in the page, spans it, and gives it a class
function getSelectedText(inputColor) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('class', inputColor);

    if(document.getSelection) {
        var selection = document.getSelection();
        if(selection.rangeCount == true) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can counter this? I've already tried using `document.oncontextmenu = false` directly following the problem line, but that's not bringing back right click. I also tried replacing it with `newNode.appendChild(range.extractContents()); range.insertNode(newNode)` as recommended by https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/surroundContents but then instead of highlighting text, it seems to just be removing it from the page.

Comment: I think the problem is that you remove the clicked element during the event handling. Try doing it inside setTimeout.

Comment: @wOxxOm that totally worked. Do you happen to know why removing the element during handling would disable right clicking of all things? Everything else, including left clicking, worked as normal.

Answer (score 1):

@wOxxOm answered my question in a comment, but a setTimeout() is what worked. So for anyone else who might have a similar issue in the future:

```
// Finds the text selected in the page, spans it, and gives it a class
function getSelectedText(inputColor) {
    var span = document.createElement('span');
    span.setAttribute('class', inputColor);

    if(document.getSelection) {
        var selection = document.getSelection();
        if(selection.rangeCount == true) {
            var range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            setTimeout(function(){
                range.surroundContents(span);
                selection.removeAllRanges();
                selection.addRange(range);
            }, 100)
        }
    }
}
```